# Why is the tone coming from my cup, caused by the strirring of my coffee, decreasing when I put creamer into it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, velocity, home-experiment

I noticed that when I put creamer in my coffee while stirring it, the tone of the ceramic cup (caused by the spoon touching the cup) is decreasing. I've searched the internet, but couldn't find any explanation.

So I tried to add the creamer slowly to my coffee. While stirring the cup the sound clearly decreased slowly in frequency.

So what causes the reduction of the speed of sound in coffee with creamer in it?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Why does the sound of my tea stirring go up in tone the faster I stir?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189424), [Why does the sound pitch increase on every consecutive tick at the bottom of a filled cup of coffee?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23038).

Comment: Please clarify - is it just "adding more liquid" that's doing this, or is it specifically creamer? One would expect the pitch to drop from adding more liquid (longer column, greater mass); but if the creamer, when heated, produces very small bubbles, the effect on sound wave velocity (and thus pitch) will be more significant.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform-Of course, the question is related, but it's certainly no duplicate since I hear the tone **de**creasing while stirring and adding the creamer.

Comment: Is this sound caused when you stir the coffee without scraping the cup? If not, are you scraping the bottom or sides of the cup?

Comment: I've actually paid no attention to this. I just stirred my coffee with a metal spoon.

Comment: Possibly due to the [Hot Chocolate Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_chocolate_effect). See also http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.13080 and http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~hemh1/coffeecup/coffeecup.htm.

Comment: According to that effect, the tone gets higher, but I hear the tone getting lower while adding the creamer.

Comment: What kind of creamer, liquid or solid?   The hot chocolate effect has entrained air, which spreads, then dissipates, while a liquid with suspended droplets will spread very fast, and dissipate only if and as the suspension clears somehow.   The spread being fast, perhaps that phase is just harder to detect.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant columns of fluid which could contain a pressure wave that is producing the sound in addition to the guess you made that the pressure wave has something to do with the interface between the spoon and liquid (i.e. the bounciness of creamer vs. the bounciness of coffee).

My guess is that you are driving an oscillation in the cup which is, in turn, driving the column of air above the coffee to oscillate and that is the sound you hear. (a quick order of magnitude calculation if you can measure the actual tone could verify this)

You are obviously causing a pressure differential in the column of coffee when you stir it a la Bernoulli's principle. However, if this was the oscillator producing the sound wave, we would anticipate that the frequency should be getting lower as the column grows, just like a pipe organ. However, this is the opposite of what you notice.

On the other hand, the column of air above the coffee is getting shorter, so if somehow your stirring causes a pressure differential here, then you would indeed hear the frequency go up as the column gets shorter when you pour in more liquid. If the cup itself is oscillating, then it is certainly possible that compression and expansion of the lip of the cup is causing this pressure wave.

I would check if you find the same effect when filling the cup with more coffee, and also check ensure that your stirring remains constant so that you are not driving different oscillations in the cup as you stir. If don't see the same effect when you fill the cup with more coffee and you can also recreate the effect when you are more careful about the stirring, then I think it's fair to say you are actually noticing an effect of the microscopic composition of the liquid.

Comment: You say that the frequency is getting lower if we produce the sound waves by an oscillator the sound would get lower, contrary to my observation. But actually, I hear the sound getting lower.